# Reading HTML file with Python Pandas into dataframe returns invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping

I am trying to read and extract tables from wikipedia it generally works for most pages but for some reason for this link it doesn't work: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Britain_at_the_Olympics'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Britain_at_the_Olympics%27)

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
ukolympics=pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Britain_at_the_Olympics')
```

Output:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '6;'
```

I am expecting a list of all tables on the page but I am getting the following error instead and I can't find the way to process the data to avoid trying to convert to int() as it's done by Pandas automatically

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the problem in wikipedia HTML file, there is an unexpected character after colspan parameter (shown below in screenshot). By editing the table and deleting ; symbol I was able to read the table using pandas.

[image]

Please see the link which shows the edit:

[Link for the Wiki edit HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Great_Britain_at_the_Olympics&diff=1074826723&oldid=1074825237)

I am interested in knowing more general solution as often it's impossible to change the table parameters.

Comment: Please, share the related link. Respondents may need to check the html structure of the provided link.

Comment: added the link, would really appreciate help